# Resume template with leading line to start section

Tags: cv

I came across a resume [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jeanyang/jeanyang_cv.pdf) and like its format, in particular the red lines that begin each section. How can I create those lines in LaTeX, and then have the years on the left column and everything else on the right column?

Also, it would be great if someone could point out a similar resume template online. I tried searching, but didn't find one quite like this.

Comment: Use the [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class with `\moderncvcolor{red}`; here's a [`template`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the template! When I tried to compile it, though, it gives error `! Undefined control sequence.
 l.13 \moderncvcolor{blue} % color options 'blu...`. Why is it so?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an outdated version of the package. Which version do you use?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - How can you check this and what should you do to update your version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely the moderncv package. Here's an MWE, slightly fleshed out:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\moderncvstyle{classic}     % style options are 'casual' (default) and 'classic' 
\moderncvcolor{grey}        % color options 'blue' (default), 'grey' and 'black'

% 'grey' makes the divider bars too dark in relation to the headings,
% so we'll override:
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0}                % regular fonts
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{192,192,192}          % headings and divider bars
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{128,128,128}          % address, phone etc.

% New color for headings:
\definecolor{mediumgrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
% Change the width of the first column
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm} 

\firstname{Nomen\vspace{0.25em}\\}          
\familyname{Nescio}

% All lines are optional:
\address{1024 Nonesuch Street}{San Francisco, CA 94105, USA}
\phone{123-456-78902}
\email{nomen.nescio@example.com}
\homepage{www.example.com}
%\photo[2.7cm][0.4pt]{photo.jpg}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{\textcolor{mediumgrey}{Personal Data}}
        \cvitem{Born}{1 January, 1900}

\section{\textcolor{mediumgrey}{Education}}
        \cventry{October 2001 – June 2002}{NTNU (Trondheim, Norway)}
{Faculty of Petroleum Engineering and Geopyhsics}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```