# How to change the color of symbols (mobile, email, homepage, etc) in moderncv?

Tags: symbols, color, moderncv

I'm able to style the contents (color, font size), but I can't change the color of the symbol.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fdpfXGM.png]

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{François}
\familyname{Tessier}
\title{Concepteur / Développeur}              
\address{<Rue>}{<CP Ville>}    
\mobile{\color{light-blue}{+44000000000}}                    
\email{mymail@mail.com}                      

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Also, for some reason I can't style the email at all, I can't change the color, fontsize etc. But it works with address, mobile, title etc. Could it be something to do with the @ symbol?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

Comment: This help? [Link formatting: colors, underlines in moderncv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/link-formatting-colors-underlines-in-moderncv)

Comment: Do you want to change the color of _only_ the links, or of the whole personal information section?

Comment: @rickhg12hs from that link, I think I might need to edit moderncv.cls.

Comment: @Xavier I want the whole personal section to be purple, both the symbols and the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is now, there is unfortunately no elegant solution to do that (yet) :(

The color of the personal information section is controlled by a color called `color2`, the secondary color of each color scheme (after the primary color `color1`, while `color0` controls the color of the main text (black)).

So you could simply redefine that color, anywhere after `\moderncvcolor` (or the deprecated `\moderncvtheme`) and before `\makecvtitle` / `\maketitle`, by:

```
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.50,0.33,0.80}
```

This will however also change the color of the other elements that rely on `color2`, such as the rendering of `\title` (on top of my mind, it is actually the only other element that depends on it in the "classic" style variant). A hacky way to counter that is to force the color of `\title` through its argument.

Putting it together:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\colorlet{titlecolor}{color2}% save the secondary color before redefining it
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.50,0.33,0.80}% redefine the secondary color to purple

\firstname{François}
\familyname{Tessier}
\title{\textcolor{titlecolor}{Concepteur / Développeur}}% force to render the title in the previously saved original secondary color
\address{<Rue>}{<CP Ville>}
\mobile{+44000000000}
\email{mymail@mail.com}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Also, do you know how to further style this personal info section and remove the italics? I'd rather the font was styled normally.

Comment: @user2130426 Just redefine `\addressfont`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mobile symbol is set *before* the mobile number. As such, your definition - that includes `\color` - changes the colour too late. You need to add the colour to the mobile symbol and it will flow through to the mobile number as well:

```
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\mobilesymbol{\protect\color{blue}\mobilesymbol}
\makeatother
```

[image]

To change the colour of other personal content on a case-by-case basis, you need to update `\addressymbol`, `\@addresscity`, `\@addresscountry`, [`\mobilesymbol`,] `\phonesymbol`, `\faxsymbol`, `\emailsymbol`, `\homepagesymbol` and/or `\@extrainfo`.

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you tell me where in that code I should enter the mobile number?

Comment: @user2130426 As usual, use `\mobile{+44000000000}` in your preamble

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,0,128}
```

to change the line, then override again for the actual text, like so:

```
\definecolor{mediumgrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\mobile{\color{mediumgrey}{+44000000000}}
```

Take a look at this example of mine: [Resume template with leading line to start section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104156/resume-template-with-leading-line-to-start-section/104180#104180)

Comment: Basically, what Xavier says.